# How to stop long downloads/uploads to iCloud when browsing with Finder shared folder in other macs on the same LAN

Tags: macos

Every time I go to Finder and I select a shared folder in other macs on the same lan I notice that there is a long delay before the content of that folder is displayed.

The network monitor of Little Snitch shows me that uploads and downloads are performed to icloud.com. When these uploads and downloads stop, the content of the shared folder is finally shown in Finder.

[image: network monitor]

How can I stop these downloads and uploads to icloud.com happening when I select with Finder a shared folder in other macs on my same LAN?

Please notice that I have the following Finder preferences:
[image: finder preferences]

And and the following iCloud system preferences:
[image]

Please notice that all my macs are on mac os x 10.12.6 Sierra.

Comment: What's your question here?  iCloud and what it syncs or the latency of opening documents on shared folders on your LAN.  These are two completely separate topics and (as framed) one has nothing to do with the other.

Comment: Agreed, network activity with iCloud has nothing to do with the local LAN. It *is* odd that you are seeing that much network activity from iCloud but slow parsing of shared resources is to be expected, especially over WiFi. It is possible you may be conflating two unrelated symptoms.

Comment: Would this phrasing make my question any clearer? When I transfer files between two computers on my lan, a large amount of download/upload to iCloud takes place before the files are actually transferred. Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

Comment: I have reworded the title and edited the body in an attempt to make the question clearer and I focused on one specific question to avoid confusion.

Comment: I have uploaded a short mp4 that shows what is happening [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mV_3G50VLYJIK8jJDy02SEMjexinW4I0/view?usp=sharing) . Am I allowed to share mp4 on this site?

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, I recommend using **SFTP** to transfer files. **SFTP** moves files using an **SSH** session. **SSH** can do authentication by user credentials, or by public keys.

It's secure, fast on modern hardware, and with modern tools, relatively convenient.

Here's one way to do that:

1. Turn on "Remote Login" in **System Preferences->Sharing** on the remote Mac (be sure to ***Allow access for: All users***)
2. Create user credentials on the remote Mac
3. Download an *FTP client* that can do **SFTP**. My recommendation is **Filezilla**.

Use the *FTP client* to log in by **SFTP** to the remote Mac, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Thank you Matt. It seems a little bit of an overkill to use (S)FTP when transferring files from/to computers on the same LAN.